# Declare array of cells depending on value

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

In Google Spreadsheet I am trying to declare an array of cells depending on the result of some operation. Switching the sign of the result I should create one, two or three elements of array (cells).

The initial algorithm is like:
`={SWITCH(SIGN(A1);-1;"1";0;"1;1";1;"1;1;1")}`
It does not work of course but the idea is to get one element for minus, two elements for zero and three elements for plus.

Have you got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you get the string, you may [`split`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) it to get the array:

`=SPLIT(SWITCH(SIGN(A1),-1,"1",0,"1;1",1,"1;1;1"),";")`

If you need a column of data, also use [`transpose`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en):

`=transpose(SPLIT(SWITCH(SIGN(A1),-1,"1",0,"1;1",1,"1;1;1"),";"))`